# check if PAGE is expired and then redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a way to check to see if the PAGE (NOT session) is expired and if so, to redirect them to another view in MVC (4)? I am not looking to reload the page if the page is expired but rather that instead of displaying the browser "This page has expired" page, to instead do something like re-execute the controller action but checking to see if that page has been expired.

any ideas?

UPDATE: Code:

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-60));
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);

            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

I don't see the page itself rendering any no cache or expires attribute/tags. not sure if it should or not

Comment: ActionFilterAttribute and setting expires in it.

Comment: I've done this but no go. I don't even see the page rendering anything about no cache or expires :-/ (updated original post to show code)

Comment: why is that -60? shouldn't it be 60?

Comment: we want to expire it in the past, not the future

Comment: If you expire it in the past, then it is *always* expired. What's the purpose of even having the page?

Comment: Good point. The purpose is to prevent the user resubmitting an application or payment or something like that. That's the purpose. I want to be able to expire the page so if they hit back, it will show the page is expired.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is a sample for callback on cache expiration.
 string test = "test1";
 Cache.Insert("Key", test, dependancy, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(DateTime.Now),    System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheRemovedCallback));

    public void CacheRemovedCallback(String key, object value, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason removedReason)
    {
        //Logs.write = "Cache Expired for : " + key;
        RedirectToAction("action","controller");
        //You can redirect or do anything else you want.
    }
```